# EF simple relations and foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework

I have a code first class

```
public class test
{        
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int ManagerID { get; set; }


   [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
   public Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

In databas table is created correctly, however then I try to access

```
pTest.Manager it returns null
```

In database table test field ManagerID has correct id value for person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Manager` property virtual so that EF can lazy load it or use eager loading(using the `Include` method).

```
public class test
{        
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int ManagerID { get; set; }


   [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
   public virtual Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tnx that did the trick - but in that case - what do this virtual mean?

Comment: @SpoksST EF will create a sub type (proxy) of your class and override the property injecting logic to lazy the property.